# What is the battery voltage for a Supermarine Spitfire?

Tags: military, fighter, electrical-system, battery, spitfire

I am used to modern aircraft being 28V systems. I found an article saying that a trolley AC plug in battery used to start WWII aircraft was 12V. I'm trying to confirm or disprove this.

Comment: That wouldn't be surprising as the cars of the time were 6V.

Answer (score 6):

This [aircraft museum](https://shortfinals.org/2013/07/30/the-trolley-acc-an-indispensable-tool-of-ww2/) says that the "Trolley Acc" (Trolley Accumulator) used for Spitfires and other aircraft supplied 12 volts. Lots of sources state that Spitfires had 12 volt electrical systems, including the [Pilot's Manual](http://zenoswarbirdvideos.com/Images/spit/Spit2Manual.pdf).